# QlikView Using an expression result as a selection or list box

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have a simple straight table that has a dimension and an expression.

```
=If(Only({1}YOURFIELD) - Above(Only({1}YOURFIELD)) = 1, 'Match', 'Check')
```

The expression either outputs `Match` or `Check`.

However I cannot select the expression results to only show `Match` or `Check` with the results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a list box using this expression:

```
Aggr(If(Only({1}YOURFIELD) - Above(Only({1}YOURFIELD)) = 1, 'Match', 'Check'), DimensionsFromYourTableHere)
```

Small Edit to show [EldadT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2342292/eldadt) how this works:

[image]

Comment: stop posting wrong answers. this will not work in a list box! the correct way will probably be to create a field that holds these values.

Comment: @EldadT It does work, as it worked for me, hence the answer

Comment: the above function cannot work in a list box...but...whatever

Comment: @EldadT Once again. Yes it does, i made you a video showing it :)  (click on it to make it full screen)

Comment: just read the help: https://betahelp.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2018/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/InterRecordFunctions/above.htm

it says that it only works in a column table...

Comment: try without the above function - do you should get the same result?